# nginx redirect to url with slash at end, from all urls with few exceptions

Tags: nginx, web-server

I need to redirect all url (with several exceptions) to url with slash on end.
Like `https://example.org/some-url` => `https://example.org/some-url/`

But I want to prevent redirect, if this is:

- file
- directory
- one of exception urls
- one of wildcard urls, that
  return file from '`style.css`', '`style.123.css`', '`style.34553.css`'

I used following config to redirect to urls with slashes at the end:

```
set $my_var 0;
if (-f $request_filename) {
  set $my_var 1;
}
if (-d $request_filename) {
  set $my_var 1;
}
if ($request_uri ~ "^.*/market/cart$") {
  set $my_var 1;
}
if ($request_uri ~ "^.*/market/order/accept$") {
  set $my_var 1;
}
if ($request_uri ~ "^.*/market/order/status$") {
  set $my_var 1;
}
if ($my_var = 0) {
  rewrite ^(.*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;
}
```

to create wildcard redirects, i used

```
location ~* (.+)\.(?:\d+)\.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$ {
  try_files $uri $1.$2;
}
```

But how can I use redirects to slashes at end with this wildcard `location`?
Maybe here is the way to make this config more right and clear.

Comment: [If is evil](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/). Do you really want to redirect or do you just want to fulfill requests for example.com/a with example.com/a/ ? The latter is done with try_files. Make your exceptions locations selected by regular expressions, not if blocks.

Comment: I need to redirect them. How can i disable redirect to '/', when url accepted with css/js/etc.. location ?

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested this myself, so it might not work. But you can try this:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri @addslash =404;
}

location @addslash {
    rewrite ^(.+[^/])$ $1/ permanent;
}

location ~ /market/cart$ {
    ... your try_files statement from configuration
}

location ~ /market/order/(?:accept|status)$ {
    ... your try_files statement from configuration
}

location ~* (.+)\.(?:\d+)\.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$ {
    try_files $uri $1.$2;
}
```

We use the `@addslash` location block for adding the slash to the URLs.

Then we use separate `location` blocks for the URLs you want to process without adding slash to end. I simplified and combined the regex patterns a bit. Here you need to copy your CMS front controller pattern `try_files` statement so that the requests are correctly passed to your CMS.

Finally we have the regex for matching images.

This should give you the behaviour you are looking for, because of the order nginx processes `location` blocks.

Comment: Thanks. I used location / {try_files $uri $uri/ <at>addslash /index.php$is_args$args;} and location <at>addslash {rewrite ^(.+[^/])$ $1/ permanent;}. But it's doesn't work. How to make this workable?

Comment: "It does not work" doesn't help with resolving the issue. You need to tell precise information what exactly happens.

Answer (score 0):

I found working solution. It uses bad practice (if is evil), but it's only working code. So if any will show better workig decision, I will be grateful.

```
set $my_var 0;
if (-f $request_filename) {
  set $my_var 1;
}
if (-d $request_filename) {
  set $my_var 1;
}
if (-d $request_filename) {
  set $my_var 1;
}
if ($request_uri ~ "^.*/market/cart$") {
  set $my_var 1;
}
if ($request_uri ~ "^.*/market/order/accept$") {
  set $my_var 1;
}
if ($request_uri ~ "^.*/market/order/status$") {
  set $my_var 1;
}
if ($request_uri ~* "(.+)\.(?:\d+)\.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$") {
  set $my_var 1;
}

if ($my_var = 0) {
  rewrite ^(.*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;
}

if ($request_uri ~* "^(.*/)index\.php$") {
  return 301 $1;
}


location ~* (.+)\.(?:\d+)\.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$ {
  try_files $uri $1.$2;
}

location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
  include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
  fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-newstom-fpm.sock;
  fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
}
```